# Information on Box

Tags: pages, numbers, keynote

updates for Numbers, Pages, and Keynote say that you can do collaborative work using **Box**.  What do we know about this "Box"?  Searching such a short word on Apple's site seems hopeless.

Answer (score 5):

This refers to [**Box.com**](https://box.com/), a third-party collaboration tool with a focus on file sharing, similar to Dropbox.

As for why this company specifically: it is known that Apple internally uses Box for file sharing, so they have an interest in integrating this platform to assist in their own use of their iWork suite.